# NextJS isn't updating when pages/containers/components are changed, HMR always returns success

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, hapi.js, hot-module-replacement

I'm having an issue with `NextJS`/`webpack`.

Whenever I make changes, it won't update anything until a full restart of everything. This takes a really long time to compile, most recently `6.4` seconds for the client and `2.3` for the server. Often it has taken `20-30` seconds in the past.

`process.env.NODE_ENV` is undefined, `webpack-hmr` and `on-demand-entries` both always return empty/success in the browser.  My guess would be that `Next`/`Webpack` aren't able to watch the files that are being changed.

My `next` version is `6.0.3` and I'm working in `Ubuntu 16.04.4 lts` in `WSL` on `Windows 10.0.17134`.

The problem persists with a custom server, I'm calling `app.getRequestHandler` once, assigning it to handler, then routing get paths (`/{p*}`) to the handler with `Hapi v17.5.2`.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to find this "question and solution" and it is still not working...

Try adding a `.env` with `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` on it, this fixed it for me, because I am not storing the files inside `WSL` but in a different disk on Windows...

Answer (score -2):

I added

```
config.node = {
  fs: 'empty'
}
```

and now it updates on file changes.

Comment: Where did you add, file name please?

Comment: Yes please, where did you add that? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @user2170889 you find a solution and you share half the answer... awesome...

Comment: after looking for some time, I found a similar solution, it is a GIST https://gist.github.com/bietkul/6c640a088f90e94982af1efd6e83b28e still did not work for me...